# Android transition in oncreate method

Tags: android, transition

I have defined the xml for two different scenes (activity_test_pre.xml and activity_test.xml) and this is the code to load the scenes, enter the first one, and finally do the transition to the other one:

```
    ViewGroup rootContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.base);

    //first scene
    ViewGroup startViews = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_test_pre, rootContainer, false);

    //second scene
    ViewGroup endViews = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_test, rootContainer, false);

    scene1 = new Scene(rootContainer, startViews);
    scene2 = new Scene(rootContainer, endViews);

    //create transition, set properties
    transition = new ChangeBounds();
    transition.setDuration(3000);
    transition.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());


    scene1.enter();
    TransitionManager.go(scene2);
```

The problem is, I have this code in the oncreate method of the activity. This way the app shows straight the second scene, without transition.

If I put the last line: 
        TransitionManager.go(scene2);
in the onclick event of a button, the transition is showed properly. I want this behaviour but I want it when the activity loads, without the interaction of the user.

Comment: try adding `rootContainer.removeAllViews()` just after declaration.

Comment: I've tried. Doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try to do the same in `onWindowFocusChanged()`

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        ViewGroup rootContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.base);

        //first scene
        ViewGroup startViews = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_test_pre, rootContainer, false);

        //second scene
        ViewGroup endViews = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_test, rootContainer, false);

        scene1 = new Scene(rootContainer, startViews);
        scene2 = new Scene(rootContainer, endViews);

        //create transition, set properties
        transition = new ChangeBounds();
        transition.setDuration(3000);
        transition.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());


        scene1.enter();
        TransitionManager.go(scene2);
    }   
}
```